# What does nest_level mean in Pry's prompt configuration?

Tags: ruby, prompt, irb, read-eval-print-loop, pry

I'm trying to configure a simpler Pry prompt for entering Ruby code.  What does `nest_level` mean?  The Pry documentation says, "Three parameters are passed into the prompt procs, the object that is the target of the session, the current nesting level, and a reference to the associated Pry instance. These objects can be used in the prompt, if desired."  Their example is:

```
Pry.config.prompt = proc { |obj, nest_level, _| "#{obj}:#{nest_level}> " }
```

However, `nest_level` doesn't seem to be what I think it is:

```
main:0> if true
main:0>   if true
main:0>     while true
main:0>       puts 1
main:0>       break
main:0>     end  
main:0>   end  
main:0> end  
1
=> nil
main:0>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nesting level refers the scope. In `pry`, you can use the `cd` command to "enter" objects, which is like using `instance_eval` - allowing you to use methods of said object without prefixing them with the object's name. For example(with the same prompt proc you used):

```
main:0> arr=[1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
main:0> cd arr
[1, 2, 3]:1> first
=> 1
[1, 2, 3]:1> last
=> 3
[1, 2, 3]:1> count
=> 3
[1, 2, 3]:1> exit
=> [1, 2, 3]
main:0>
```

I've `cd`ed into the array, and called it's method without prefixing them with `arr.`. The nesting level was changed to 1 when I `cd`ed into it, and went back to 0 when I `exit`ed. I could also use `cd ..` to exit the scope.